# Rearranging $\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Consider the complex series: $$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^k.$$
Clearly the series converges for $\left|z+\frac{1}{2}\right| < 1$, by the ratio test. I am supposed to write this in terms of powers of $z$, and check that the series doesn't converge for $z = -1$. I've done some work, but I'm having trouble concluding. We have:

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^n \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^k &= \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{r=0}^k {k \choose r} \frac{1}{2^{k-r}}z^r \\ &= \sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{k=r}^n {k \choose r} \frac{1}{2^{k-r}}z^r   \\ &=\sum_{r=0}^n \left(\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n-r} {\ell + r \choose r} \frac{1}{2^\ell}\right)z^r  \end{align}
  $$

Assuming I didn't mess up here, I would have to check that: $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{r=0}^n \left(\sum_{\ell = 0}^{n-r} {\ell + r \choose r} \frac{1}{2^\ell}\right)(-1)^r$$ doesn't exist. I have no idea of how to deal with the double sum here. I am at a loss. What to do?

Also, it is not completely clear to me why rearranging the terms yields a different result. Is it because of the $-1$, which causes some negative terms to appear on the sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sum is equal to, where it converges,

$$\frac1{1-(z+1/2)} = \frac{2}{1-2 z} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{k+1} z^k$$

Interestingly, this converges for $|z| \lt 1/2$.  Thus, the former sum may be seen as an analytic continuation of this sum.

Comment: Nice, I should have thought of the geometric series. Thanks. But this doesn't really gives an insight about that last crappy limit...

Comment: First, as $n \to \infty$, the inner sum indeed converges to $2^{r+1}$, so the sum agrees with my simpler result.  But the point was to simply derive the series.  Your way was a mess.  I showed you a much cleaner way that didn't require the evaluation of binomial sums.

Comment: Yes, your way is much cleaner. I understood that for $z = -1$ things go wrong because $|-1| > 1/2$. But I fail to see why the inner sum indeed to to $2^{r+1}$. We have $n$ in the upper limits of both sums, and you're taking the limit only on one sum...(this is like saying $(1+1/n)^n \to 1$ as far as I understand)

Comment: @IvoTerek: the binomial coefficient $\binom{\ell+r}{r}=\binom{\ell+r}{\ell}$ is the power series coefficient of the function $(1-x)^{-(r+1)}$.  This is a well-known result.

Comment: @LutzL: a) I have no idea what you are talking about and b) I am not trying to justify anything about the binomial series - the OP is.  I showed him the likely intended way for him or her to solve the original problem.  I apologize for sounding hostile, but questions about binomial series, which completely derail my original point that the solution does not need all of this complicated double summation, leave me a bit exasperated.  Please pose the question to the OP.

Comment: Sorry, did not get the whole picture at first, reading some context into it that is not there. Your answer is the most straight-forward way, there is no reason to seek more complicated computations.

Comment: I've been away a bit, but don't fight, guys. @Ron, about "sounding hostile", don't worry, I am not offended at all. On the contrary, thanks for giving more explanations. I suppose I should just study more about series, my background isn't all that good. I understood how to approach the problem, and I'll pay more attention to the geometric series. I really didn't knew about the expansion of $(1-x)^{-(r+1)}$. Well, eventually it would show up. :)